# Can't write images using jspdf in phonegap

Tags: pdf, cordova, cordova-3, jspdf

I need to generate a pdf and export data(including images) to the generated 
pdf in ios cordova by using the file transfer. I got succeded in generating 
pdf and writing normal text but not images. When I have tried to export 
image I got success alert in "writer.onwrite" function but not finding the 
image in the pdf. But the pdf file size got incremented.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

jspdf support only jpeg. Is this the image type you use.
I m also trying to generate a document with image but the jpeg header is not properly interpreted on the android device while its ok on a regular device.

Did you go through this issue before? 
Also I m a bit confused on what get output with the jsPDF.output and how to translate this to a file ?

Comment: Actually it also support PNG since early this year.

Answer (score 0):

changing pdf generation from

```
var pdfOutput = doc.output();
```

to

```
var pdfOutput = doc.output(“blob”);
```

worked to fix the issue of images being not included into the pdf in jsPDF version 1.0.209.